# Are conjugation map of $\mathbb{HP}^{n}$ and identity map on $\mathbb{HP}^{n}$ homotopic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am curious to know whether the conjugation map on  $\mathbb{HP}^{n}$ and the identity map on $\mathbb{HP}^{n}$ are homotopic or not. Initially, I tried to construct homotopy explicitly but it seems not to come from anything. Any kind of hint/suggestion is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarity: What is $\Bbb{HP}^n$?

Comment: @Arthur: Presumably the quatrrnionic projective space.

Comment: Hint: Look at the action on the 4th homology group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you please tell how  get generators of $H_{4} (\mathbb{HP}^{n})$ ? I mean we know that its 4th homology group is $\mathbb{Z}$ but what is the explicit generators?

Comment: Do you know the standard CW complex structure of the quaternionic projective space? If you do not, you should work it out by analogy with real and complex projective spaces. Then use cellular homology to answer your question.

Comment: Yes using cw structure... getting 4th homology of it is $\mathbb{Z}$ as it has one cell in each 4k dimension. But i couldn't figure out generator.

Comment: So you know how to calculate CW homology as an abstract group, but you do not know how to represent individual elements of homology? If that is the case, you might benefit from studying the *proof* of the CW homology calculation.

Comment: Consider reading, say Hatcher's book with a description of cellular homology of real and complex projective spaces. This includes explicit description of generators. Make sure you understand it. Then repeat in the quaternionic case.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out properly. It will be of great help if anybody can write and explain answer for $n=2$ in of the main question.

Comment: I see no evidence that you have tried something to solve this problem. According to the MSE rules, such questions should not be answered.